# chatbots load a MediaWiki page

Tags: chat, mediawiki, html, telegram-bot

Is it possible in Facebook Messenger, or Telegram, or KiK, to load a MediaWiki page into a Chatbot?

I have a MediaWiki page with a lot of business coaching content.

I would like to create a Chatbot that accesses and displays this content.

Are there any tools for loading a Wiki into a Chatbot?  I believe this has been done in WhatsApp: https://www.quora.com/Whatsapp-wiki-service-how-does-this-service-work

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a **url** in telegram, a preview for the webpage is loaded automatically.

For your bot content, you could the call`sendMessage` function and use the `disable_web_page_preview` property to control the web preview of urls embeded in your messages.

However, I would suggest that send pre-formatted or pre-cached Wikipedia HTML content as responses to specific user commands/requests to your bot.